# Creating a deeply nested dictionary from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently struggling with an issue. I have a file that contains one 5 letter word per line. Lets say for example the words are
Hello
Hella
Pales
Piles

I am trying to create a nested dictionary with each key corresponding to the letter in the word. For example with these words the output would be.

```
{'H':{'e':{'l':{'l':{'o':'Hello','a':'Hella'}}}}, 'P':{'a':{'l':{'e':

{'s':'Pales'}}}, 'i':{'l':{'e':{'s':'Piles}}}}}
```

I have tried some code that almost works, but does not produce the right results.

```
T={}

for w in wordsFile:
        T[list(w)[0]]={list(w)[1]:{list(w)[2]:{list(w)[3]:{list(w)[4]:w}}}}
return(T)
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this. I just am not quite sure as to go about solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should do its job:

```
def add_to_dict(dictionary, word):
    current_dict = dictionary
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if i == len(word) - 1:
            current_dict[letter] = word
        else:
            if not letter in current_dict:
                current_dict[letter] = {}
            current_dict = current_dict[letter]

dictionary = {}

add_to_dict(dictionary, "Hello")
add_to_dict(dictionary, "Hella")
```

Or you could use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def nested_dict():
    return defaultdict(nested_dict)

def add_to_dict(dictionary, word):
    current_dict = dictionary
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if i == len(word) - 1:
            current_dict[letter] = word
        else:
            current_dict = current_dict[letter]

def to_dict(dictionary):
    dictionary = dict(dictionary)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, defaultdict):
            dictionary[key] = to_dict(value)

    return dictionary

dictionary = defaultdict(nested_dict)

add_to_dict(dictionary, "Hello")
add_to_dict(dictionary, "Hella")

dictionary = to_dict(dictionary)
```

Comment: When I run this code the output is not a simple dictionary. Im not quite sure how to explain the output... the dictionary is there but inbetween each key is defaultdict (<function Boggle.readData.<locals>.nested_dict at 0x1057d3d08

Comment: Yes. Those are instances of `defaultdict`. It's different type, but it behaves like dict. I've updated the answer, now the return value contains only pure dicts.